# Node.js - res.end and res.write can accept a callback function

Tags: node.js, callback

When creating a basic HTTP server with Node.js, I noticed that the `res.write` and `res.end` methods of the '`http.ServerResponse`' object can both accept a callback function like so:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    res.write('Hello ', function() { console.log('here 1'); });
    res.end(' World', function() { console.log('here 2'); });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

'Hello World' is output in the browser, and 'here 1' and 'here 2' is output into the terminal.

However, these callback arguments aren't documented anywhere, for instance http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding unless I'm missing something.

Can I really use these callback functions? I have an interesting use case for them. Or are they some internal use thing and should be avoided?

Comment: it's most likely `res.write('hi', function(err) {});` might be one more parameter as well, but I've never used it passed the singular `(err)`

Comment: response.write does not provide an error callback. The second arguments is supposed to be encoding only.

Comment: I dug through the node code and didn't really find how those functions were being executed. Below are the two defintions of those functions. 
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L393 https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L468
You can follow the encoding value around and you'll end up  at https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L147

Comment: And then if you look at connection.write in the net module you'll see the encoding and cb can be optional. That is where it is actually being called.

Comment: Ah, I guess I needed to go one step deeper down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a 'feature'. It is actually meant to be the encoding to be used in the body but the way the net module works is the second argument is an optional callback.
The stack is like this (about)

```
res.write(data, encoding)
res._send(data, encoding)
res._writeRaw(data, encoding)
res.socket.write(data, encoding, cb)
```

At that last point the number of arguments changes from 2 to 3. data and encoding to data, encoding, optional callback. So what is happening is your function (as the encoding argument) is being passed to socket.write where encoding can be optional.

This could be considered a bug as you cannot push all three arguments from the response write method. I'd advise using it with extreme care.

Comment: Good analysis. I'd advise definitely not using it. The only reason it works is due to javascript's super loose/dynamic typing. At any point someone could decide to be a little stricter with their code and it would suddenly stop working. But more importantly it's just confusing/hacky code. Truly a hack that just happens to work at the moment.

Comment: It also appears to be different in the master branch, so might not even work already.

Comment: Here is the actual point where the encoding turns into a callback. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/61c9f78c639459f28eea3d1de203b92debd9f513/lib/_stream_writable.js#L175

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at the changes, it slightly older versions (what I had checked out) it happened in net.js